# Hover event isnt being triggerd for all divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a page with a background and a content div, one overlapping the other. The div with a class of "content" receives the hover event however the div with a class of "background" receives nothing. I'm not actively disrupting the event in js in any way.

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.background {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background" onmouseover="test(this)">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- PANELS -->
    <div class="facePanel" onmouseover="hoveringFacePanel(this)" onmouseleave="hoveringFacePanelOff(this)">
      <img class="imageShown" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/70/d4/22/70d422d5972596f603a94c0faf24a43d--advertising-design-advertising-campaign.jpg" />
      <img src="https://apple.insidercdn.com/gallery/21413-24435-Screenshot_1-l.jpg" class="imageShown" />
    </div>
    <!-- PANELS -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/6ardv95r/

UPDATE:

The bubbling nature of events was brought up however this doesnt answer why this behaviour still occurs even when the html is turned into this:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="background" onmouseover="test(this)">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this case the content class doesnt capture any hover event but still no event triggers the background class. Upon removal of the content class the background class works as expected..

Comment: Can you show your JS?

Comment: heh yeah thanks, fixed, been staring at this longer than i'd ideally want to

Comment: WizardCoder, theres literally 3 empty functions in the js file that simply print out stuff. By removing the div with the class "content" the background div receives the event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser events work through a process called "bubbling" - they start at the most specific tag and then work their way up the tree (from child to parent to grand-parent, etc) until they reach the root tag (usually <html>).

In your case, mouseover and mouseout events get triggered inside the "content" div and bubble up, but they aren't contained within the "background" div **in terms of the DOM tree**, even if they are contained **visually** (with the content rectangle being drawn as "inside" the background rectangle).

In this case the "content" div appears after the "background" div, so it is rendered "on top" and gets all the events, while "background" gets none. If you want the background to get the events too, put the "content" div **inside** the "background" div.

More info on event bubbling here: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: So in other words them being siblings means that the last sibling will be the one to take precedence. The issue is that they sort of need ( ? ) to be siblings as i want one to be an overlay over the other

Comment: Children can overlay over parents - just make the "content" div fill the background completely.